# Java evaluate if multiple boolean parameters are equal

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

I was implementing an N-nary tree (here N=4) and want to put in a logic to do something if the boolean property `val` of all four children of a node are equal, I tried with:

```
if (childOne.val == childTwo.val == childThree.val == childFour.val){
    doSomthing();
}
```

however this doesn't work for my test cases, so I have to change it to a more explicit and verbose:

```
if (childOne.val == childTwo.val && childTwo.val == childThree.val && childThree.val == childFour.val){
    doSomthing();
}
```

and this one works. However I cannot make sense why the first evaluation doesn't give me the correct answer.

Comment: `a == b == c` equals `(a == b) == c`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `==` operator is left associative, so your first expression looks like this with brackets added:

```
(((childOne.val == childTwo.val) == childThree.val) == childFour.val)
```

Here's a case where the above will be true, but not all four values are the same:

- child 1 and 2 are false
- child 3 and 4 are true

Another way of doing this:

```
Stream.of(childOne.val, childTwo.val, childThree.val, childFour.val)
    .distinct().count() == 1
```

I suggest you stick with the plain old `&&` because there isn't a `BooleanStream` and the booleans need to be boxed.

Comment: that's absolutely correct, thanks! I was mistreating it with `=`, also https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/ appears to be a good reference with the associativity properties for all operators listed.